# reverse bias of the gate of an N-channel enhancement mosfet

Tags: mosfet, physics, reverse-breakdown, device-characteristics

So how negative can I drive the Vgs of an N-channel Mosfet before damage occurs?  Datasheets specify BVDSS and BVGSS but these are "forward" breakdown voltages -- ie the absolute maximum Vds before avalanche breakdown of the drain body pn junction, and the maximum gate drive voltage before the electric field breaks down the gate oxide. I can't find the "negative" breakdown voltages in the device specifications.

Does the susceptibility of the gate oxide to an excessive e-field then suggest that the maximum "negative" Vgs is the same as the BVGSS specified but in the opposite polarity?

EDIT:  Here's a portion of the p-channel device I was looking at that prompted the question:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All datasheet specified Vgs_max for example.

[image]

In this case "negative" (minus) 20V is the maximum value.

Comment: yep, it is obvious from that data sheet, thank you.  The datasheet of the device I was looking at (a P-channel, CSD25213W10) does not specify it... Unfortunately, I can't add the pic here...  It specifies it  only as BVGSS Gate to Source Voltage; VDS = 0V, IG = –250μA –6.0 V (min)  I asked the question in terms of an N-channel to avoid any confusion, knowing that i would understand how any given answer would apply to the p-channel device.   So, although the datasheet for the CSD25213W10 does not specify the maximum reverse Vgs, it is then understood to be +6V? see updated question question....

Comment: Yes, it will be +6V  because if the MOSFET substrate was not short together with a source (due to physical construction) it will be a fully symmetrical device.